# Alternative to wood furring strips?

Tags: patio, pool

Just bought a house with a pool. The pool decking is comprised of large, square concrete pads that are separated by wood furring strips. The prior owner has used pressure-treated 1x2s atop a small gravel bed for drainage. I'm looking for an alternative to the wood that won't bow and will retain its aesthetic qualities for a long time. Options I've considered are things like Trex, Extira, decorative gravel. Someone told me about a soft, permeable material that holds its shape to provide the nice, clean edge, but helps drainage, but I can't remember what it was.

Any ideas on what materials I can consider? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Trex = composite decking. That.

Answer (score 1):

I’d consider plastic furring strips. Contact a company that makes plastic planks, (i.e.: for park benches, etc.) You can cut and shape the planks to any size, it’s rot-proof, and is not susceptible to expansion and contraction.

Comment: Thanks, Lee. I'll do the research on plastic furring strips.

Comment: UHMW is a very good long lasting plastic. I have 2 strips on the bunks of my boat and they have lasted almost 35 years and other than some scratches they still look almost new.

Comment: UHMW is also very _slick_. It's used as the "bearings" in model railroad cars and as fence faces in wood working tools because it's got a very low friction factor. I'm not sure I'd recommend that, @EdBeal, for a walking surface next to a pool. (Even just small filler strips in the walking surface.)

Comment: @freeman, there are many finishes available cast into the UHMW sheet, usually only black or white color but my mill purchases sheets with a nice cross hatch pattern to maintain some “slickness” and still have a surface that can be walked on. It is expensive but will outlast us at a home.

Comment: Totally not my experience, @EdBeal, didn't know it existed. #TIL - thanks!